# ArcGIS vector tile layer label gets underneath satellite image after pan or zoom esri-leaflet-plugin

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online, esri-leaflet

I am trying to render on a leaflet map an ArcGIS vector layer and a satellite image layer using the [Esri Leaflet Vector Tile plugin][1]. The issue is that when I add those two layers the labels of the vector layer disapear underneath the satellite image after we pan or zoom in the map.

For reference I am trying to load this vector tile layer https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=28f49811a6974659988fd279de5ce39f on top of the world imagery map.

Code exampe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Esri Vector Layer</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <!-- Load Mapbox GL -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css"/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

  <!-- Esri Leaflet and Esri Leaflet Vector -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet/dist/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-vector/dist/esri-leaflet-vector.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {margin:0;padding:0;}
    #map {position: absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([ 40.706, -73.926], 14);
  L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png').addTo(map);
  L.esri.Vector.layer('28f49811a6974659988fd279de5ce39f').addTo(map);
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use explicit map panes. https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the zIndex property resolved the issue:

```
L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png',{ zIndex: -1 }).addTo(map);
```